# Getting transform.rotation.z value from an animated view

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, cabasicanimation

I'm spinning continuously an `UIImageView` using `CABasicAnimation` and I want to be able to get the rotation angle.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self spinAnimationOnView:self.myImageView
                        duration:2
                          repeat:HUGE_VAL];
}

- (void)spinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration repeat:(float)repeat{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

The animation behaves as expected. But then I try to get the rotation angle like this:

```
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[self.myImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

NSLog(@"ROTATION = %f", angle);
```

And the output is always 0. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an animation is in progress, you need to use the CALayer's `presentationLayer` to get the state of the layer. See the [CALayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW63).

```
CGFloat angle = [[self.myImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

NSLog(@"ROTATION = %f", angle);
```